# Ruby on Rails - how to make a clippy widget work from a helper file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a app/helpers/application_helper.rb file with this code:

```
  def clippy(text, bgcolor = "#ffffff")
    text.gsub!('"',"'")
    path_to_swf = "/flash/clippy/clippy.swf"
    html = <<-EOF
      <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
              width="110"
              height="14"
              id="clippy" >
      <param name="movie" value="#{path_to_swf}"/>
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
      <param NAME="FlashVars" value="text=#{text}">
      <param name="bgcolor" value="#{bgcolor}">
      <embed src="#{path_to_swf}"
             width="110"
             height="14"
             name="clippy"
             quality="high"
             allowScriptAccess="always"
             type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
             pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
             FlashVars="text=#{text}"
             bgcolor="#{bgcolor}"
      />
      </object>
    EOF
    raw(html)
  end
```

and I am trying to use it in an HTML file (I use HAML so it is really a HAML file) but I am not sure what I need to do in order to actually call that code above and render the little clippy widget.

I have this HAML code to try to render the clippy:

```
.clippy-container=clippy("hello","#ffffff")
```

and I do that in a file located in app/views/my_file.html.haml

Any idea what I need to do in order to make the clippy render?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't there a problem with

```
app/views/my_file.html.haml
```

Shouldn't it be

```
app/views/some_controller/my_file.html.haml
```

I tried your code, it works fine!

Comment: ah yes, the path is that. I just didn't want to give the long path because I thought it might be easier to read if shorter.

Comment: @Wava Loo to make it work on your end, did you just copy the clippy snippet into your HAML?

Comment: Yes, I copied the exact code in ApplicationHelper and one of my views. Of course it was blank, because there was no SWF in `/flash/clippy/clippy.swf`. Maybe you should check the source code.

Comment: does the flash have to be in the namespace I am working in? Could that be the problem? Should it be something like flash/my_namespace/clippy.etc ?

Comment: I don't think so. If the flash is in your Public folder, it should be fine. Do you see the object code in the source?

Comment: @Wava sorry, what do you mean object code in the resource? :) I am a bit new to Ruby terminology :)

Comment: I just checked public/flash/clippy and the swf file is there!

Comment: In the HTML source code of your page, can you see the <object> code? (sorry, I wasn't clear enough)

Comment: Yes I see it. You will laugh what the fix was. Flash seemed to have crashed on my browser and I had to reinstall the flash :)

Comment: Thanks for the vote and the accepted response! Using Chrome on a Mac?